# ASP.NET: How to access Session from handler?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, handler, ihttphandler

i'm [trying to store some values in the **Session** from a *Handler* page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051305/asp-net-how-to-redirect-prefilling-form-data), before i do a redirect to a WebForms page, that will pick up the **Session** values and pre-fill the WebForm:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   {
      ...
      context.Session["StackOverflow"] = "overflowing";
      context.Response.Redirect("~/AnotherPage.aspx");
      ...
   }
   ...
 }
```

Except `context.Session` object is null.

How do i access Session state from a handler?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Implement the [System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) interface

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
{   
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  
  {      
    context.Session["StackOverflow"] = "overflowing";      
    context.Response.Redirect("~/AnotherPage.aspx");      
  }

}
```

Comment: Note: you don't have to actually implement anything, just add the interface to your class. The web-server then sees that you're asking for it, and fills it in.

Comment: Yes which is still implementing the interface but since it's a marker interface there isn't any code we have to write other then the deriviation of the interface.

Comment: For some reason mine wouldn't work, even with `IRequiresSessionState` specified. I had to use `IReadOnlySessionState`. I haven't researched why yet, but it is working..

Answer (score 10):

Implement `IRequiresSessionState`

Answer (score 7):

Does implementing [iRequiresSessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate.aspx) resolve this?

What about doing an IHttpModule instead and overriding BeginRequest?

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone know which is better performance-wise?

Comment: i am facing same problem i used iRequiresSessionState  in my handler code but still i can't access session values. session keys are still 0. can anyone tell me about this?