# Triggering download from PageMethod. What's incorrect?

Tags: c#, serialization

I am attempting to trigger a download of an XML file stream from a PageMethod. I followed the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream.aspx)

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Export()
{
    bool successful = false;

    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Dashboard.xml");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;

        SerializableDictionary<string, string> dataToSave = new SerializableDictionary<string, string>();

        foreach( var state in StateManager.StateDictionary)
        {
            var sessionItem = SessionRepository.Instance.GetSession(state.Value);
            if (Equals(sessionItem, null)) continue;

            using( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(sessionItem.GetType());
                serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, sessionItem);
                dataToSave.Add(state.Value, Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()));
            }
        }

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSave.GetType());

        using( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, dataToSave);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", memoryStream.Length.ToString());

            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            using( StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

        successful = true;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.ErrorFormat("Unable to serialize session. Reason: {0}", exception.Message);
    }

    return successful;
}
```

I receive no warnings or errors. Just finishes successfully with no download.

EDIT: I've tried application/xml and text/plain as ContentTypes, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the response headers:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=fname.ext")
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString())
```

Comment: Ahh.. that would explain how I could name the file, too. Lemme try it out!

Comment: Is there a way to get the length of the stream? Look at the line where I serialize dataToSave to a stream. OutputStream.Length isn't accessible, I beleive.

Comment: IIRC, you can serialize the data to a string, get the length of the string and then write the string to the response using Response.Write. Flushing should then complete the response.

Comment: Do you know if reading the MemoryStream's length property would be acceptable? I've implemented the other way and am checking it now, was just curious if there was any difference between MemoryStream length and the string length derived from the MemoryStream.

Comment: Not sure.. Couldn't hurt to try... I would try it out myself, but I'm using my home mac atm... :P

Comment: Haha it's all good. I did try it out. Still no download, though! Going to post my updated code, 1 second.

Comment: Another approach would be to serialize it to string, convert to bytes and the do Response.BinaryWrite(byte[])

Comment: The method of serialization shouldn't have any affect on how the browser processes it, yeah? Seems like the issue is somewhere else. I'm wondering if I can do this inside of a page method?

Comment: WOW! I'm such a dunce... You're right... WebMethod is not the right way to do this. I didn't even notice the attribute... Using a handler (ashx) would be the correct type to use.

Comment: Let me check that out. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if it will be possible to target/call/whatever this ASHX file from client-side? That's why I was using a PageMethod in the first place.

Comment: Session is null inside of the ASHX? :( Got it :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058568/asp-net-how-to-access-session-from-handler

I AM on top if things... :)