# Generic Handler and SQL Server connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, generic-handler

I have this code in Generic Handler to connect to database and retrieve the image from table,

But when user logging on will choose the database,
for example:

```
my database is: SH001

user: username

Password: password
```

I save the database in `Session["db"]` when logging in

and when the user go to products page and searching for products...it list the products with their images...

but since I changed the connection from:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DVR;DataBase=SH001;User ID=userid;Password=password");
```

to:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DVR;DataBase=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["db"] + ";User ID=userid;Password=password");
```

it starts to give me an error when retreive the image in products page

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

this is the code in the Generic Handler:

```
public class image : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=DVR;DataBase=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["db"] + ";User ID=userid;Password=pass");
        string image = context.Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select Image from Products where ID = '" + image + "'", Con);
        Con.Open();

        SqlDataReader Reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (Reader.GetValue(0) != DBNull.Value)
            {
                context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])Reader["Image"]);
            }
        }
        Con.Close();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do some extra work to access the Session from the handler. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058568/asp-net-how-to-access-session-from-handler

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: How to access Session from handler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058568/asp-net-how-to-access-session-from-handler)